# Telegram Bot API. Как избавиться от сообщений в хаотичном порядке?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Приветствую!
Я хотел бы спросить, как избавиться от сообщений в хаотичном порядке. Код самого бота здесь: https://gitlab.com/snippets/34169

Происходит вот что: если бот выключен или же сразу быстро отправить боту три любых сообщения, то в ответ может прийти что-то вроде "картинка-картинка-текст-автор-картинка-текст-автор-текст-автор", хотя ожидаемый результат должен быть таким: "картинка-текст-автор-картинка-текст-автор-картинка-текст-автор". Суть в том, что мне хотелось бы отделить картинку (и возможно еще какие-нибудь атрибуты) к новости от самого текста новости.

Был бы признателен за совет, в какую сторону копать, чтоб сообщения приходили в строго определенном порядке.
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Зачем вам хочется разделить новость на три сообщения? Логичнее её предоставлять в виде одного сообщения. Тем более, что у ботов возможности для форматирования текста гораздо шире чем у обычных пользователей

Comment: Код бота(класс ImmateriumBot) в сниппете вы не привели - только код его использующий, не содержащий ничего полезного.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, весь код доступен тут: https://gitlab.com/amelin/immateriumbot/tree/master Я хочу сначала отсылать картинку, потом текст новости.

Comment: Тьфу. Затупил. Подумал, что от сервера телеги приходят эти три сообщения в неправильном порядке. Отправляйте всё одним сообщением. Не делите его на три части. Представьте, что кто-то захочет сделать форвард Вашей новости, а она разбита на три части.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Отвечу сам себе для истории:** чтобы сообщения приходили в строго определенном порядке, следует использовать конечные автоматы.

Пример использования есть тут: https://groosha.gitbooks.io/telegram-bot-lessons/content/chapter11.html